# Export My WxPython GUI

Tags: wxpython

I have built a WxPython GUI for QA of a Device.

I want to send it to a team who are not developers.

My problem is that it has many python(2.7) modules/libraries:

```
import wx
import xlrd
import wx.lib.masked as masked
...
```

can you please recommend a way so they will have an easy time using my GUI?
(I think they are using windows)

My target is to instruct them only on how to install Python and then hit a button for the rest.

i don't want to make my GUI public, just send it to those guys.

Comment: Take a gander at http://www.pyinstaller.org and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Python executable creation tool. Here are the most popular ones:

- py2exe
- pyInstaller
- cx_freeze
- bb_freeze

These can turn your application into an executable so that the end user doesn't need to install Python, wxPython or any of the other Python libraries. I also recommend learning how to use an installation wizard such as Inno Setup or NSIS to create an installer that will make this sort of thing even easier for your end user.

I wrote up an example of how to do this sort of thing here:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/27/packaging-wxpymail-for-distribution/